# Finding a file by typing out its first letters on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

In some folders there are files who have similar names, say

```
AuthorA_2005_PaperOnSomething
```

or

```
AuthorA_2006_PaperOnWord
```

Usually this problem does not occur and when I start typing, the first hit is the file that I want but I this case, if I continue typing it won't "switch" to "AuthorA_2006".

How can I do that? Is that even possible with the vanilla Windows Explorer?

Comment: Rather than typing, try pasting the search word all at once

Comment: have you tried using the tab key to auto complete what you are typing?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/a/114698/161391) answer might help. In particular, [Listary](http://www.listary.com) looks like what you might require.